# i do want to create a opportunity line item record automatically based on Product entry in detail level

Tags: apex, process-builder

We have a requirement to create a opportunity line item record automatically based on Product entry in opportunity detail level. Product values are captured at the opportunity level through custom field. I tried to do it through Process builder, i am unable to stamp the pricebookid

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a trigger on the Opportunity (simply retrieve the PricebookId [or use the standard] and create an OpportunityLineItem for the Product in question), but I'd strongly suggest a push back on this requirement.